# In dataframe, there is customername, invoiceno, invoice _date, due _date,date and totaldays(days)

Tags: group-by

one customer has many invoice , for particular invoice has many record as per day one record untill payment date. so date column start from invoice_date till untill payment date. I.e, customer A, has one invoice where invoice date Jan 1, 2023, due_date 2nd feb 2023 and date or record start from janaru 1 untill  May 23, 2023 so total for this invoice till 2nd Feb 0 after one day for one record untill end of record. I would like to show in aggregate level Customer name, End of Month (As Month Year) and MAX NO of due days except last of of record. There is alos column for total due days.

Thank You!

I tried on sql , could not solve , traying in python